# segmentation fault and array issue

Tags: c++, windows, memory, segmentation-fault

I've been going back trying to find a segmentation error in my program. Very often when the program crashes it is at this point.

```
unsigned long data = octets[g];
```

So I have tracked this buffer as being created in the main loop with a fixed defined size. However since it's defined in a if statement in main does it need to be allocated with "new"? Basically after receiving from a TCP socket the char buffer is copied to an unsigned char buffer to check for certain binary data types. So only if data arrives is this called into existance.

```
INT8U byteArray[BUFFERSIZE];
```

This buffer is then passed for message ID and crc checking. Is not doing a "new" type allocation the issue because it is in the main loop? I thought it would go out of scope at the end of the "if new data is received" statement.

```
long calc_crc24q(byte* octets, int start, int last) //start is first byte, last is MSbyte of CRC
{
  long crc = CRC24SEED;
  for(int g = start; g < last; g++) //should xor from preamble to the end of data
  {
    unsigned long data = octets[g]; //fault occurs here often
    crc =  crc ^ data << 16;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
      crc <<= 1;
      if (crc & 0x1000000)
      crc = crc ^ CRC24POLY;
}
  }
  return crc & 0x00ffffff; //returns an int value with high byte 00 then data in lower 3 bytes
}
//---------------------------------------------
```

Here is the message id

```
unsigned int id_message(INT8U* buffer, unsigned int posStart, unsigned int numberbytes, unsigned int& messageLength)
{
unsigned int messID = 0;
unsigned int posEnd;
unsigned int noBytes = 0;

if(buffer[posStart] == Preamble)
{
    unsigned int dataLength = (((0x0000 | buffer[posStart+1]) << 8) | buffer[posStart+2]);  //0x byte1  byte2
    messID = ((0x0000 | (buffer[posStart+3] << 4)) | ((buffer[posStart+4] >> 4) & 0x0F)); //byte1 shift 4 bits add upper 4 bits of byte 2
    noBytes = dataLength + 6;
    //numberbytes = noBytes;         
    posEnd = posStart + noBytes - 1;
            if(calc_crc24q( buffer, posStart, posEnd-2) != (((0x00000000 | buffer[posEnd-2]) << 16) | ((0x00000000 | buffer[posEnd-1]) << 8) | (0x00000000 | buffer[posEnd])) )
    {
        cout << "CRC error" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    //return message type extracted from data segment
    messageLength = posStart + noBytes;
    return messID;
}
return 255; //unknown type
}
```

Comment: Depends on how it is defined. `if(condition) {INT8U byteArray[BUFFERSIZE]; doStuff(byteArray); calc_crc24q(byteArray)}` will be valid

Comment: `if(condition) {INT8U byteArray[BUFFERSIZE]; doStuff(byteArray);} calc_crc24q(byteArray);` will not be valid.

Comment: @user4581301 OK, well my initialization should be valid but now I wonder if I'm overflowing the stack running it that way. The max size is 1029 bytes. So from some reading I've done it sounds like I should be using the heap for large arrays.

Comment: 1029 bytes is peanuts unless you're working on an embedded system, and an old one at that. If you have less than a 4k stack, I'll be amazed. The default stack under Window's is a meg. Not sure with desktop Linux, but certainly somewhere in the same ballpark. Have you marched through this with a debugger?

Comment: @user4581301 I've been trying to figure this out with the debugger in CodeBlocks.

Comment: I have changed the array to dynamic allocation but have the same result. I got this from the debugger in CodeBlocks:     #0 0041030D calc_crc24q(octets=0x344b18 "Óþ\212§´ø\003{", start=0, last=65165) (C:/Users/Josh/Documents/code/RTCM3.h:104)
#1 0041055C id_message(buffer=0x344b18 "Óþ\212§´ø\003{", posStart=0, numberbytes=12, messageLength=@0x22fdf4) (C:/Users/Josh/Documents/code/RTCM3.h:187)
#2 00437AEF main() (C:\Users\Josh\Documents\code\main.cpp:570)
The seg fault always occurs on the same line.

Comment: If the buffer that `octets` refers to is of length `BUFFERSIZE` which you say is 1029 bytes, the debugger message above says that `last` is 65165. Your line `for(int g = start; g < last; g++)` will march `g` way past the end of the buffer if this is the case. It's hard to say, but from your description, maybe you are calling `calc_crc24q` with `start` and `end` values referring to a larger buffer that is accumulating from multiple recv calls, but setting `octets` to the temp recv buffer? Hard to say w/o seeing the code that is invoking `calc_crc24q`

Comment: I have been looking at those functions for days and never realized this issue. Also I was passing the received bytes to the messageID function but not using it to limit the number of bytes checked for the message length.

Comment: Looks like I went to sleep at the wrong time. @DavidLaPorte is right on the button. Working back, the 2nd and 3rd bytes of buffer (Óþ\212§´ø\003) are `þ\212`. þ is an ASCII character with hex code FE. \212 is unprintable so the debugger gives you the value 212 in octal (8A hex) . Combining to get dataLength, you get FE8A or 65162 in decimal.

Comment: Following through I get noBytes = 65168, posEnd = 65167, and last = 65165. So buffer makes no sense or the messages are much larger than you expected. For safety, you should have a reality check `if (dataLength > BUFFERSIZE){ //Handle error}`, but you need to go digging back a bit further to find why the buffer either contains garbage or exceeds the length expectation.